# Would I be able to browse a classic ASP website in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, asp-classic, internet-explorer-11

I am able to browse in IE 10 using compatibility mode and adding the website to intranet zone/ trusted zone. I am not sure of IE11. We are planning an organisation level upgrade to IE11. Please let me know your recommendations for classic ASP apps. Thanks.

### Elaborating my question by adding two more questions:

1. What are those ASP things/components/functionalities which will fail in **IE11** but they run successfully in **IE8**?
2. What are those ASP things/components/functionalities which will fail in **IE11** but they run successfully in **IE10**?

Comment: Sorry Deepak, but I think the addition of the two questions in your [latest edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25909151/3) just makes your question to broad. By default IE 11 will use "Standards" mode to render your web front-end, if your web applicaton does not use "Standards" mode then you will have issues with CSS, HTML and may be even "client side" script like JavaScript (depending on what it does, accessing the DOM etc). But that is just the tip of a very large complex iceberg. This is why IE provides a "Compatibility View", to support legacy methods.

Comment: I know and I apologize too... I think I am getting extra cautious or I am trying to be double sure :)

Comment: That is understandable, but if you can save yourself a lot of pain and heartache by moving away from legacy rendering techniques and move towards using "Standards" mode.

Comment: How to do that? Can I configure that in IIS to run in standard mode?

Comment: No it comes down to what [`<!DOCTYPE>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration) you use and how you write your "client side" script. The rules vary based on DOCTYPE, the website [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is a brilliant resource for this type of thing, I'd recommend you take a good look at it. Remember it is the "client" (Internet Browser) not the server (IIS) that is responsible for "Quirks" mode, "Standards" mode, "Compatibility View" etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic ASP is a [server side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) technology, compatibility mode is for "client side" (i.e.. Internet Browser) compatibility issues with CSS, HTML and JavaScript.

Whether you have problems upgrading to IE 11 will depend on how outdated your coding techniques are when building your web application front-end.

You have already said

> *"I am able to browse in IE 10 using compatibility mode and adding the website to intranet zone/ trusted zone"*

so in terms of IE 11 you should have no issues as compatibility mode in IE 11 is almost identical.

Browser Standards are evolving all the time, it may be best to consider upgrading from something like [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) to Standard Mode which is now better supported across all major Internet Browsers.

---

> If you interested in knowing a bit more about what can be done the [Modern.ie](https://modern.ie/) site is very good it has a [Compatibility Scan](https://modern.ie/en-gb/compat-scan) that will allow you to scan your webpages and have it report back.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, I mean, what are those things in classic ASP website which will fail to function in IE11 but they will function in IE8 without any problem?

Comment: @DeepakMishra I think you may have missed the point. Classic ASP will function fine, but if you have "server side" code written in ASP that builds HTML for the "client side" that uses "Quirks" mode you may find you need to run your IE browser in Compatibility mode.

Comment: I am ok with running in compatibility mode but are there any issue which can come even after running the classic asp website in compatibility mode in IE11?

Comment: @DeepakMishra Absolutely you may find trying to use newer JavaScript frameworks and plugins cause you problems would be one example. Either way this is **not** a dependency on Classic ASP, this could happen with any website creation method, static, dynamic regardless of technology (php, asp.net, classic asp, ruby etc).

Comment: I think I can trust you..There should not be any major issues with IE11 as we already tested with IE10.